# Symfony2 Get array from URL via POST

Tags: symfony

I send some data by POST.

For example: http://.../?tag[]=1&tag[]=2

I cant receive tag varible in controller, I tried to do something like this:

```
$this->get('request')->get('tag');
```

But I receive null.

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sending data as you mentioned via URL, it is a GET request.

```
public function exampleAction(Request $request)
{
    $tagPost=$request->request->get('tag');     //from $_POST[]
    $tagGet=$request->query->get('tag');        //from $_GET[]
    var_dump($tagPost,$tagGet);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right. But I think it was Advanced REST for Google Chrome extension error. Now I receive tags.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
$this->get('request')->request->get('tag');
```

instead of:

```
$this->get('request')->get('tag');
```

EDIT: IF you http method is GET (instead of POST), you can try with:

```
$this->get('request')->query->get('tag');
```

Check [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_fundamentals.html#requests-and-responses-in-symfony) for further detail

hope this help

Comment: Thanks, you are right. But I think it was Advanced REST for Google Chrome extension error. Now I receive tags.